# Wordpress 2-column theme CSS problem

Tags: css, wordpress-theming

I created a wordpress blog (http://raptor.hk), but i am unable to set the right sidebar into correct position. i think i have missed something in CSS. the DIV is named "rightbar". I would like the DIV to be positioned right next to the content, within the white wrapper. Also, support of fluid layout (not moving on browser resize) is needed.

the problem is solved (see my answer), but anybody can give better solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

I put the DIV just inside the #main DIV, and set the following:

```
position: relative;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-right: 5px;
float: right;
width: 200px;
border: none;
border-collapse: collapse;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting the following styles for the div id "rightbar".

```
position: absolute;
top: 200px;
right: 300px;
```

That will put the "rightbar" div at the top of the page, just under the header and to the right.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but this solution does not work for fluid layout (on resize, the position will move)